# Intellij method body formatting: bracket and cursor placement

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I recently updated to 2016.3 and it seems importing settings from previous versions isn't exactly working as it should, again.

The bracket and cursor placement used to be as follows:

```
public void bla() {|}
```

<enter>

```
public void bla() {
    |
}
```

But now, after pressing enter, it looks like this:

```
public void bla() {
|}
```

<enter again>

```
public void bla() {
// no indent here
|}
```

Does anyone know the settings that gets this back to normal? I've gone over all the relevant settings groups but can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically a bug report/support request and should be directed at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Why are there lots of other questions just like this then? This post isn't so much about the broken import but about getting the formatting right, which is similar to other posts found all over the site.